# Enable/Disable htaccess with PHP?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, directory

Is there a way to disable htaccess to website users? What I need is htaccess to disable only to a select group of my website users to access a directory full of uploaded images and to the non-selected user have htaccess enabled to stop them from accessing the directory!

Any help would be great!

Comment: Anything you can put into an `htaccess` file you can put into the apache configuration. Do that and turn of htaccess entirely. As a bonus you'll get improved performance, security, and stability.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll want to do this:  Basically redirect all requests to a php file which then does the access control.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CheckAuthorizedToFile.php?file=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

CheckAuthorizedToFile.php

```
<?php


$basepath = '/path/to/images/';
$realBase = realpath($basepath);

$userpath = $basepath . $_GET['file'];
$realUserPath = realpath($userpath);

if ($realUserPath === false || strpos($realUserPath, $realBase) !== 0) {
//prevent directory traversal by exiting execution
exit();
} 

if($_SESSSION['IsAllowedToViewFiles']===true)
{


$file = $_GET['file'];
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
}
else
{
echo "Not Autorized please login.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

htaccess is managed outside of php (e.g. by apache environment) and is scanned and executed before the php script starts. So the answer is NO.

This is related to "Enable/Disable htaccess with PHP?"
Apache itself can manage access control by users. But this is again outside of PHP control.

Possible PHP solution: Disable access of a directory by apache for all, and deliver  content/files by php after user verification.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Also you can use [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) to limit access to the directory, but it's only usable if the directory is directly accessed.